# Animations created in Texmaker not working in PDF X-change Viewer

Tags: animations, animate

At [this site](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-definite-integral/) there is a very cute example of an interactive animation.
If I *download* the PDF directly, it works fine in both Adobe Acrobat *and* in PDF X-change viewer (the latter is my preferred pdf-program).

If I download the *sourcecode* and compile it in Texmaker, it only works in Adobe. 
In PDF X-change the animation/figure is invisible.

The same applies to animations I create myself by looping images etc.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Hi, and thank you for replying.

When i download the animation (pdf) from the link above it works fine in both PDF programs.

When i compile the attached code in TexMaker it only work in Adobe.

So pdf x-change viewer is capable of displaying animations, but not when i compile them myself. I wonder why..

Comment: Hmm, that is a bit more trickier. Perhaps the versions are not the same. Could you supply pdf version information.

Comment: @zeroth: Here is PDF-information:

Downloaded PDF (works in both programs):
PDF-producer: pdfTeX-1.40.9
Application: LaTeX with beamer class version 3.07
PDF-version: 1.4


Self-compiled PDF (only works in adobe)
PDF-producer: pdfTeX-1.40.13
Application:LaTeX with Beamer class version 3.32
PDF-version: 1.5

Comment: Update: I tried chaning minorversion to 4 without any change in result. I also tried to change the document type to article (since the beamer version was different). But no to avail. The compiled document still only works in acrobat while the downloaded one works in both.

Comment: I can't really find out if anything strange has happened in pdftex (doesn't seem like it), try and downgrade your beamer and tikz versions to the "public available versions". Also I am not aware of anything regarding the `animate` package perhaps @AlexG can help us?

Comment: For the record, it has to have something to do with your TeX installation, not with Texmaker, hence I have removed the tag.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your effort.
I can try to download another tex-program and see if the result changes.

_edit: same result with TexNic_

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know animations would work in PDF X-Change. The PDF from the link in the OP was produced with an old `animate` version `[2009/05/07]`. I'll try and find what has changed in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful reply, @AlexG. I wish to add that the code successfully compiled and displayed correctly in pdf x-change using the onlinetool "writelatex.com".

Comment: @AlexG Did you find any differences in the animate function?

Comment: Yes, I am working on the issue.

Comment: I just caught myself looking for a "like" button. Anyways, I am very thankful for your effort, @AlexG

Comment: I think I got it back. However, I am running X-Change through Wine (Windows emulation) on my Linux box, and animations are not really running. Only stepping works, by clicking the '<' and '>' controls. The same happens with the old PDF from the texample link.

Comment: I see. The animations still run normally in adobe acrobat and other pdf-viewers? (not sure which is used in linux)

Comment: Animations work well in A-Reader 7 and newer on all platforms. This is the reader `animate` has been targeted at. How does X-Change perform with resp. to the frame rate of animations, when run on Windows? – AlexG 4 mins ago

Comment: @AlexG: The fps seems to quite high I think. The infinite integral animation at max speed shows about 3-5 complete animations pr second. Being 40 frames for one complete loop, that makes it about 120-200 fps. It was varying abit when playing at higher speeds than 120 fps, but was very stable at 120.

Answer (score 1):

PDF X-Change Viewer support is back since version 2014/02/06 of `animate`.